# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am using PyROOT (an extension module for ROOT) in an attempt to create a histogram from another histogram for a particle physics data analysis course. I am consistently receiving a " 'float' object is not callable' " error when I attempt to divide and multiply lots of values in one line.

```
from ROOT import TFile, TDirectory, TTree, TH1F, TCanvas
import math
import numpy as np

myfile = TFile("/home/hilary/root/compile/Research/angle_smearing.root")
hist = file.Get("Zenith_Angles")
hgm = TH1F('Fvsx', 'Smearing_Test_1',100,0,90)

for i in range(1, 100,1):
    for y in range (1, 100, 1):
        u = hist.GetBinCenter(i)
        N = hist.GetBinContent(i)
        o = 1
        x = hist.GetBinCenter(y)
        F = (N/(o*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))*math.e((-(x-u)**2)/(2*(o**2)))) 
        hgm.Fill(F)

c1 = TCanvas()
hgm.Draw()
c1.SaveAs("/home/hilary/Desktop/Out_going_muons_etc/smearing_test_1.png")
```

The error occurs in the line that reads

```
F = (N/(o*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))*math.e((-(x-u)**2)/(2*(o**2))))
```

The error is " TypeError: 'float' object is not callable "

Comment: This seems to be a simple typo; the function is `math.exp`.

Comment: Do you understand the problem?  Some variable in that line is a `float`, but it is being used as though it were a function, e.g. `foo(...)`.  There are only two function like expressions in that line, `math.sqrt(...)` and `math.e(...)`.  All other uses of `()` just group math operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.e` is a constant `float` value; did you perhaps mean [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp), a function that returns `e` raised to the power of the provided argument?